# How are global variables stored in memory?

Tags: c, global-variables, objdump

I have code as follow:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int g_a;
int g_b;
int g_c;

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

And build it with gcc

```
gcc -o global global.c
```

Finally, I use objdump to see address of global variables

```
objdump -t global
```

And see the result:

```
00004020 g_b
00004024 g_a
00004028 g_c
```

Why are global variables stored in addresses like above? I mean global variables should be stored in order g_a, g_b, g_c

Comment: It's surprising, but not wrong, for the compiler to reorder the variables.  There is no requirement on the layout of global variables except they can't overlap in memory.

Comment: Is the same true for local variables? Are they contiguous in memory?

Answer (score 5):

> global variables should be stored in order g_a, g_b, g_c

No, the order in which they're allocated to memory in no way affects whether or not they can be accessed.

If you want them in a specific order, you can do that by putting them in a `struct` and declaring that, something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int g_a;
    int g_b;
    int g_c;
} tOrderGuaranteed;

tOrderGuaranteed myStruct;

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world\n");
    // Use 'myStruct.g_a' rather than 'g_a'.
    return 0;
}
```

But, as stated, this doesn't seem to buy you much, especially since the compiler is free to insert padding as it sees fit, between and after those members.

Provided you use `g_b` to access that (original non-struct) variable, and not some weird (undefined behaviour) variant like `*(&g_a+1)`, your code will work fine regardless of how things are laid out in memory.

Comment: You can union type pun the struct with an array of `int[3]` and then assert that the struct and array are of the same size. It eliminates hypothetical padding and allows you do use the variables as an array.